# ruby on the rails routing into controller function with dot

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am pretty newbie to ruby. How to route 'DemoController/function1' in this format 'DemoController.function1' in ruby on rails 5??

```
class DemoController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def function1
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by routing with dot. Can you please explain your question a little more.

Comment: Are you asking "how do I create a custom route"? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Have you read [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: what i want to achieve is to call function1 in this format,
foo.com/demo.function1

Answer (score 1):

According to [Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) you can do it like this:

```
get '/demo.function1', to: 'demo#function1'
```